# Gazebo simulated PR2 robot maximum speed is not respected

Tags: ros

Running ROS melodic, gazebo version 9.11.0 and the official Gazebo/PR2 plugin.

I am using a PR2 robot simulated within gazebo and sending control commands through ROS. However the robot is moving at most within 0.25 m/s while the maximum speed is 1 m/s (as per specification). I'm using the teleop application provided by PR2/Gazebo plugin.

The PR2 teleop launch file `teleop_keyboard.launch` correctly indicates the correct value

```
<launch>
        
    <node pkg="pr2_teleop" type="teleop_pr2_keyboard" name="spawn_teleop_keyboard" output="screen">
      <remap from="cmd_vel" to="robot1/base_controller/command" />

      <param name="walk_vel" value="0.5" />
      <param name="run_vel" value="1.0" />
      <param name="yaw_rate" value="1.0" />
      <param name="yaw_run_rate" value="1.5" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

Accessing the robot1 odometry directly indicates the problem: the maximum speed is somehow capped at 0.261 m/s. But the walking velocity in pr2_teleop is set to 0.5 m/s!

```
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.261318236589
      y: 4.47927095593e-06
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -1.72120462594e-06
  covariance: <removed>
```

Comment: How do you know by looking at the rostopic echo output that the twist.twist.linear.x is actually capped at 0.261 m/s ?

Comment: Did you check if the setpoints are changing when you give keyboard commands in the shell where you ran the `roslaunch pr2_teleop teleop_keyboard.launch` ?

Comment: @csg I have tried sending twist commands directly using cmd_vel and also have tried using teleop_keyboard. The odometry linear twist (xy)  speed never increased past 0.261. In case a set a speed below that value it is correctly  replicated. I'll check the setpoints.

Answer (score 0):

According to `teleop_pr2_keyboard.cpp` the values of `geometry_msgs::Twist` have to be:

```
0.5 for twist.twist.linear.x -> forward moving

-0.5 for twist.twist.linear.x -> backward moving
```

and so on, see http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/pr2_teleop/html/teleop__pr2__keyboard_8cpp_source.html.
My question is how do you get a so minimal deviation in `linear.y` and `angular.z` and did you change something in the above mentioned file?

Comment: I did not, the teleop is in its original version. I suspected this small change was due to simulation error (PR2 has lots of moving parts). I'll evaluate this.

Comment: You know you have to use your remapped topic. Instead of cmd_vel use the topic robot1/base_controller/command.

Comment: thanks, I did that indeed. I have two robots are receiving commands independently and it works the only problem is the maximum velocity.